# Selecting all objects from a list that return true on a member function, as a list?

Tags: c#, linq, list

I'm new to LINQ and trying to get a hold of it.

It's been useful so far for various things such as cutting down the code required, like when using `.ForEach()` to run a function on every object.

Now I'm trying to get a list of all objects from a master list, when their `IsMouseOver()` function returns true.

As a standard `foreach` it looks like this:

```
this.m_EntHovered.Clear();
foreach (EntEditor ent in this.m_EntAll)
{
    if (ent.IsMouseOver(mousePos))
        this.m_EntHovered.Add(ent);
}
```

But I wanted to shortern this using LINQ, however the shortest I could get it wasn't much shorter:

```
this.m_EntHovered = (from ent in this.m_EntAll
                    where ent.IsMouseOver(input)
                    select ent).ToList<EntEditor>();
```

Is there a better way to achieve what I'm after or is what I'm doing fine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't necessarily a better way to do it, but you can write it more succinctly via:

```
this.m_EntHovered = this.m_EntAll.Where(ent => ent.IsMouseOver(input)).ToList();
```

Note that this is not the same as your original, however, as you're assigning a new list, instead of adding items to the existing list.  To get the same behavior (which may not be needed), you could do:

```
this.m_EntHovered.Clear();
this.m_EntHovered.AddRange(this.m_EntAll.Where(ent => ent.IsMouseOver(input)));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I knew there was a shorter way of doing it, I just couldn't find the right LINQ function.

Comment: @MatthewMcGovern Alot of Linq extension methods accept predicates like this. `Single`, `Any`, `First`, ect.

Comment: In response to your edit, surely those lists end up with the same results? If I have a list with objects already in it and I assign it a new list, it's the same as clearing and adding them?

Comment: @MatthewMcGovern It may be, it may not be.  If there are other variables referring to that same list it's the difference between whether they see a mutated list or the old list.  Either could be preferable in certain situations.